# Finding a function which is a mapping reduction of A to B

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

How do I precisely define the function which is a mapping reduction of A to B for the following examples?

What is the process of figuring this out?

Given: A and B are languages over the alphabet {0,1}.

Examples:

- A is the language described by 1*0*, B is the language described by 01*0*
- A={w | the length of w is even}, B={w | the length of w is odd}
- A=B={w | the length of w is even}
- A={0,1}*, B={00,1,101}

I am studying this material and I am not sure of how to 'precisely' define these functions. Could somebody provide me with solutions and a methodology to finding the solution?

Comment: I think TMs should be made for the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are as follows, just functions with input w:

- f(w) = 0w
- f(w) = 0w
- f(w) = w
- f(w) = 00

Basically make sure all scenarios which occur in A are mapped to B and that all which are not, do not map to B

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel Why the unnecessary edit (of a 4 year old answer)? The previous reduction was already correct :-)

Comment: @chi I reviewed an edit which improved the formatting, but additionally changed the reduction. So I improved the edit to only change the formatting.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel I see, thanks. I was puzzled by the change, but did not read the full edit log.